# Trouble Implement Yolov3 loss function in keras

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

i created this loss function for yolo, after looking at eh formulas online. but for some reason it consume lot of memory and it is not efficient, i think there might be something that i missed and made a mistake while implementing it.
can any one of you explain the mistake.

```
def yolo_loss(y_actual, y_predicted):
      
    #  print(y_actual.shape.as_list())
    #  print(y_predicted.shape.as_list())
      c = 4
    
      class_loss = 0.0
      loc_loss = 0.0
      l_coord = 5
      obj_conf_loss = 0.0
      noobj_conf_loss = 0.0
      l_coord2 = 0.5
    
      for b in range(len(y_actual)):
        for j in range(len(y_actual[0])):
          for i in range(len(y_actual[0][0])):
            for k in range(len(y_actual[0][0][0])):
              pred_inverse = k*9
              # classification loss
              for cl in range(5,5+c):
                class_loss += (y_actual[b,j,i,k,cl] - y_predicted[b,j,i,pred_inverse+cl]) ** 2
    
              # localization loss
              x_loss = (y_actual[b,j,i,k,0] - y_predicted[b,j,i,pred_inverse+0]) ** 2
              y_loss = (y_actual[b,j,i,k,1] - y_predicted[b,j,i,pred_inverse+1]) ** 2
              w_loss = ( (y_actual[b,j,i,k,2] ** 0.5) - (y_predicted[b,j,i,pred_inverse+2] ** 0.5) )** 2
              h_loss = ( (y_actual[b,j,i,k,3] ** 0.5) - (y_predicted[b,j,i,pred_inverse+3] ** 0.5) )** 2
              loc_loss += ( l_coord * (x_loss + y_loss) ) + ( l_coord * (w_loss + h_loss) )
              # object or not loss
              if y_actual[b,j,i,k,4] == 1:
                obj_conf_loss += (y_actual[b,j,i,k,4] - y_predicted[b,j,i,pred_inverse+4]) ** 2
              else:
                noobj_conf_loss += l_coord2*(y_actual[b,j,i,k,4] - y_predicted[b,j,i,pred_inverse+4]) ** 2
                
      return ( class_loss + loc_loss + obj_conf_loss + noobj_conf_loss)
```

Comment: What error are you encountering?

Comment: @yuRa it takes lots of time to calculate error and i get OOM. out of memory.

Comment: i tried it on colab with GPU.

Comment: The issue is that you are not using a vectorized implementation. You have 5 nested for-loops which will slow dow here, the time-complexity is O(n^5).

Comment: @yuRa ok thanks, i will try to use vectors now.